# VB.net custom control – "RichTextButton"

Tags: vb.net, button, custom-controls, richtextbox, rtf

I am trying to develop/source a "rich text button" for use in Visual Studio Winforms VB.net-based applications.  The idea is that this `RichTextButton` control would behave exactly like a standard VB.net `Button`, except that it would accept and display RTF-formatted text content, i.e., a raw rtf-formatted text string containing markup+text for potentially kerned, subscripted, superscripted, multi-fontsize, etc., single-line text rendering. I.e., some kind of multiple inheritance mash-up of `Button` and `RichTextBox`, were that possible – mostly `Button` but with rich rather than plain text on display.

I feel certain that there are many possible roads to this – I have certainly explored many over the last week – however, my coding prowess has proved completely insufficient to the task (I have been close on a couple of occasions, but in each instance the result has proved embarrassingly inelegant).

Any ideas, pointers or (ideally) code for the best most elegant solution gratefully appreciated!

BTW, if not entirely obvious, I am a complete VB.net novice and, on that basis alone, would really like to avoid WPF-based solutions if I possibly can.